# Setting default value for @Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm trying to set the value for `@Html.EditorFor` in the view by razor engine.

But the value is not displaying in the browser when I run the application. What is the issue?

Here is my editor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new {  @Value = "Divaya Sree" })
```

Comment: NEVER set the value attribute (unless your trying to make binding fail) Set the value `model.FirstName = "Divaya Sree"` in the controller before you pass your model to the view.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be initialize the model in your controller itself and pass the model to view

```
model.FirstName = "Divaya Sree";
return View(model);
```

Now you can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Or this also will work

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FirstName, new { @Value = "Divaya Sree" })
```

Comment: I do not want from model and using Html.TextBoxFor. My requirement is strike to Html.EditorFor.

Comment: EditorTemplate is not supposed to work like that, also you cannot set default value in MVC 4 for editor template like that. Either you have to use model or TextBoxFor helper

Comment: @user2474052, `EditorFor()` does NOT support adding html attributes in MVC-4 (you need at least MVC-5.1). And _"I do not want from model"_ is nonsense and shows no understanding of the fundamental basics of MVC and model binding. Set the value of `FirstName` in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: Thanks and I don't want from model means I don't want from view model. I hope you got that.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { value = "Divaya Sree" } })
```

Comment: View:

        <div class="editor-label">
            FirstName:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @value = "Divaya Sree" } })
        </div>


Controller: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {

            return View();
        }

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.